# Notes become silent after move in logic

Tags: midi, logic-pro

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

So I have a few notes at the end of the midi region, and I tried to move them to the beginning of the region (mouse drag or cut/paste), but after that all the notes become silent.

As you can see, in the background there is a bar chart. I don't know what it stands for exactly, but when the notes are moved, that stays unchanged. My problem probably has something to do with this inconsistency.

Could anyone help?

Logic version: 10.3.2

Comment: Did you record it with sustain pedal?

Comment: no, i used a linnstrument.

Answer (score 3):

In garage band those bars visualize expression. Could be the beginning of the region has 0-values for expression, which would mute the sound

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your session in this screenshot in Logic
2. Click "Window" on the top menu on the screen
3. Click "Open Event List"
   (1-3 can be shortcut by holding (COMMAND 7)
4. Deselect all blue colored boxes EXCEPT for "Notes"
5. The "Val" column(Value) is the pressure at which the note is struck(80 is default)

Hope this helps!